# Using SSL_want before performing SSL_read or SSL_write operation?

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl

I planned to use `SSL_want` call before performing read or write operation so that we can avoid SSL errors like `WANT_READ` or `WANT_WRITE` . Please provide your suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you do that. What's your question?

Comment: My question is Using SSL_want before SSL_read/SSL_write is correct. Steffen Ullrich responded that it wont works.

Comment: @Ganesh - EJP is right, so you should not get offended. Stack Overflow functions best when there's a clear problem statement and a clear question (or related questions). Asking for a suggestion does not fit well. For example, I might suggest you visit the [`SSL_want(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_want.html) docs; or I might suggest you check the return value from `SSL_want`. All are valid answers since they are worthy suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work like this. SSL_want just reads the current state, which is set by SSL_read and SSL_write. So using SSL_want without a preceding SSL_read or SSL_write makes no sense.